# Is there a distinct difference between the two(desktop launcher and shell script)

Tags: 12.04

1. I made a shell script(bash), It's named `startup.sh`
2. Then I made also Desktop launcher in, `~/.local/share/applications/my.desktop`

I thought 1) and 2) were the same. But they do not behave in the same manner:  The two command receive different Environment variables.  The process from "startup.sh" has a "http_proxy" variable.

The process form `my.desktop` doesn't have a `http_proxy` variable.

I want to have the two commands use the same environment variables.

If have tried using the setting for `my.desktop` `terminal=true`, which causes that program to act the same as startup.sh, but also causes a terminal to pop up, which I do not want.

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to do with the script

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the Exec line in your .desktop file to run the script.

If this doesn't help add a line at the beginning of the script with cd folder-containing-the-script. Some scripts need this.